# How to cache server results in GWT with guava?

Tags: java, caching, gwt, guava

In my GWT Application I'm often refering several times to the same server results. I also don't know which code is executed first. I therefore want to use caching of my asynchronous (client-side) results.

I want to use an existing caching library; I'm considering **guava-gwt**.

I found this example of a Guava **synchronous** cache (in [guava's documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)):

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

This is how I'm trying to use a Guava cache **asynchronously** (I have no clue about how to make this work):

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {

               // I want to do something asynchronous here, I cannot use Thread.sleep in the browser/JavaScript environment.
               service.createExpensiveGraph(key, new AsyncCallback<Graph>() {

                 public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                   // how to tell the cache about the failure???
                 }

                 public void onSuccess(Graph result) {
                   // how to fill the cache with that result???
                 }
               });

               return // I cannot provide any result yet. What can I return???
             }
           });
```

GWT is missing many classes from the default JRE (especially concerning threads and concurrancy).

How can I use guava-gwt to cache asynchronous results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood what you want to achieve is not just a asynchronous cache but also a lazy cache and to create one the GWT is not a best place as there is a big problem when implementing a GWT app with client side Asynchronous executions, as GWT lacks the client side implementations of `Future`s and/or Rx components (still there are some implementations of RxJava for GWT). So in usual java what you want to create can be achieved by :

```
LoadingCache<String, Future<String>> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, Future<String>>() {
    public Future<String> load(String key) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        return  service.submit(()->service.createExpensiveGraph(key));
    }
});
Future<String> value = graphs.get("Some Key");
if(value.isDone()){
    // This will block the execution until data is loaded 
    String success = value.get();           
}
```

But as GWT has no implementations for  `Future`s you need to create one just like

```
public class FutureResult<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
    private enum State {
        SUCCEEDED, FAILED, INCOMPLETE;
    }

    private State state = State.INCOMPLETE;
    private LinkedHashSet<AsyncCallback<T>> listeners = new LinkedHashSet<AsyncCallback<T>>();
    private T value;
    private Throwable error;

    public T get() {
        switch (state) {
        case INCOMPLETE:
            // Do not block browser so just throw ex
            throw new IllegalStateException("The server response did not yet recieved.");
        case FAILED: {
            throw new IllegalStateException(error);
        }
        case SUCCEEDED:
            return value;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something very unclear");
    }

    public void addCallback(AsyncCallback<T> callback) {
       if (callback == null) return;
       listeners.add(callback);
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return state == State.SUCCEEDED;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        state = State.FAILED;
        error = caught;
        for (AsyncCallback<T> callback : listeners) {
            callback.onFailure(caught);
        }
    }

    public void onSuccess(T result) {
        this.value = result;
        state = State.SUCCEEDED;
        for (AsyncCallback<T> callback : listeners) {
            callback.onSuccess(value);
        }
    }

}
```

And your implementation will become :

```
    LoadingCache<String, FutureResult<String>> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, FutureResult<String>>() {
        public FutureResult<String> load(String key) {
            FutureResult<String> result = new FutureResult<String>();
            return service.createExpensiveGraph(key, result);
        }
    });

    FutureResult<String> value = graphs.get("Some Key");

    // add a custom handler
    value.addCallback(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            // do something
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // do something             
        }
    });
    // or see if it is already loaded / do not wait 
    if (value.isDone()) {
        String success = value.get();
    }
```

When using the `FutureResult` you will not just cache the execution but also get some kind of laziness so you can show some `loading screen` while the data is loaded into cache.

Comment: What you want is not that hard to implement, it's just up to you to add a success callback handlers to the ``FutureResult``. I will update a source code example to reflect my idea. But you should understand that the callback will be called just once at first load (which will be cached). So after callback the ``result.isDone`` will be true.

Comment: Check out CompletableFuture instead - it behaves more like a Promise, though you'll need to throw exceptions if anyone uses any of the blocking Future methods.

Comment: @ColinAlworth does GWT support `CompletableFuture` ?

Comment: No, I was suggesting it as an alternative to implement instead of Future. At least one other person has expressed interest in helping to implement this in GWT so that all users have this in the future, but I haven't seen any patches yet.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! One tiny note: I think `return service.createExpensiveGraph(key, result);` has to be `service.createExpensiveGraph(key, result); return result;`.

Comment: I think a method like `addCallback`, that automatically calls `onSuccess` or `onFailure` in `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED` state would be handy - and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to cache the asynchronous call results, you can go for a 
**Non-Loading Cache**, instead of a Loading Cache

In this case you need to use *put, getIfPresent* methods to store and retrieve records from cache.

```
String v = cache.getIfPresent("one");
// returns null
cache.put("one", "1");
v = cache.getIfPresent("one");
// returns "1"
```

Alternatively a new value can be loaded from a *Callable* on cache misses

```
String v = cache.get(key,
    new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
        return key.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

For further reference: https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/JavaCachingwithGuava.pdf

Comment: This is not was I was looking for. The first example will only help storing values by key, but not provide any help for loading data. The second example will only be able to handle synchronous loading.

Comment: What I thought was you can put the result into cache once you get it in `onSuccess` of asynchronous call back.